# Обновление элемента на странице

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Как сделать асинхроное обновление страницы, то есть я подгружаю с бд количество лайков,
при нажатии на "лайкнуть" у пользователя не должна обновиться страница, а всего лишь обновиться количество лайков.

Для обновления лайка нужно сделать запрос на другой файл, то есть сайт/rep.php?clanid=100

Answer (score 1):

При клике на "лайкнуть" отправляем [ajax-запрос](http://learn.javascript.ru/ajax-intro) на "сайт/rep.php?clanid=100". На сервере, при запросе определенного типа (скорей всего тут get надо) на "сайт/rep.php?clanid=100" php-скрипт обращается к базе и просит у нее текущее количество "лайков". Получив их, скрипт отправляет их клиенту. После получения ответа сервера, используя [базовые навыки манипуляций с dom посредством javascript](http://javascript.ru/tutorial/dom) , заменяем старое количество лайков на новое.